# Matrix-vector multiplication in the Compressed Sparse Row method in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sparse-matrix

Can anyone help me on how to implement Matrix-vector multiplication in the Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) method in Pyspark & Python?

`y = A * X`

Where `A` is represented in CSR format in three matrices `Val`, `RowPtr` and `Col`. Also `X` is a vector.

Matrix `A` is a sparse matrix that is stored in CSR using three arrays:

`Val[N]`: contains the value of the non-zero elements

`RowPtr[N]`: contains the row-index range of the non-zero elements
(the last element in RowPtr is the size of Val array)

`Col[N]`: contains the column-index of the non-zero elements

You can refer to [here](http://%20http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/3-C/sparse.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format) to know more about CSR matrix representation.

The algorithm is as follows:

Multiply matrix (stored with Compressed Sparse Row method) with vector `d[N]`:

```
for (k = 0; k < N; k = k + 1)
    result[i] = 0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1)
{  
    for (k = RowPtr[i]; k < RowPtr[i+1]; k = k + 1)
    {  
        result[i] = result[i] + Val[k]*d[Col[k]];
    }  
}


n = len(dense_matrix)

# res = dense X csr
csr_row = 0 # Current row in CSR matrix
for i in range(n):
start, end = row_ptr[i], row_ptr[i + 1]
for j in range(start, end):
    col, csr_value = col_idx[j], csr_values[j]
    for k in range(n):
    dense_value = dense_matrix[k][csr_row]
    res[k][col] += csr_value * dense_value
csr_row += 1

print res
```

Comment: What is the point that you need help with? Don't you have the algorithm already? Where is the problem? Also, do you need to implement that yourself or would you be fine using some pre-implemented solution?

Comment: scipy.sparse` implements it, with a mix of python and cython

Comment: @hpaulj I have edited the question. with python implementation but I need heads up for pyspark implementation

Comment: Again, what particular part are you struggeling with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How to implement the above algorithm as a map-reduce form in pyspark.